# Filter android logcat ouput for multiple tags

Tags: android, adb, logcat, android-logcat

I want to capture logs and dump them into a text file, I am using a perl script to do this. The issue I am running into is that I want to include  only certain tags in my logcat command.

I am using

```
 $adbcommand_logcat = "start \"Android-Logcat\" cmd /c \"adb -s $sno logcat -s ^(?=.*?\babc\b)(?=.*?\bxyz\b)(?=.*?\bpqr\b).*$ | -v threadtime | tee ".$mainlog_filename."\"";
```

but this gives me a blank log instead of the log with tags specified in the regex. If I take out -s after logcat then the regex does not works and log includes everything.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work using the following command with egrep.If you don't have the tag try to find the process name and use it instead.

```
 $adbcommand_logcat = "adb -s $sno logcat  -v threadtime | egrep \"tag1 or Process 1| tag2 or Process 2\" |tee ".$mainlog_filename;
```